# url rewriting remove file name "news.php?url=" from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

url is Dynamic
I have url 
**xyz.com/news.php?url=Facebook-launch-new-messenger-news-16680.php**

but Here i want to remove "**news.php?url=**" from my above url.

I'm coming on this from my index page by clicking on link

```
<a href="news.php?url=<?= $row['url'];?>"><?= $row['title'];?></a>
```

I use this rewrite code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).php$ news.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).php/$ news.php?url=$1
```

help me.

Comment: visit this site for .htaccess related help, they even have a .htaccess rule generator for prettifying urls . Link : http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561403-htaccess-url-rewrite.aspx

Comment: I don't think that you can remove the ?url= part (except if you use the post method instead of the GET method) but, to remove the news.php, just put it in a folder and rename it index.php

Answer (score 1):

Try below code rule, it will work for non existing php files..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).php/?$ news.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it is fine but url data is not coming on page.

Comment: Hey bro. Can you help me solve my other htaccess problem. check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001226/500-internal-server-error-is-coming-when-im-redirecting-my-normal-page-to-amp-p