# 500 Internal Server Error is coming when i'm redirecting my normal page to AMP page htaccess error

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect

This is my normal page code for Redirect AMP page.

```
<meta name="original-source" content="https://www.themobilesapp.com/<?= $abc; ?>">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.themobilesapp.com/<?= $abc; ?>">
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification/<?= $abc; ?>">
```

Normal page url is
https://www.themobilesapp.com/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029

This is working fine and AMP page url is not working https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029
but this amp works fine when I add **ampspecification.php** and other passing.

But when is visit on AMP page url then it is showing me this below error:-

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
>   contact the server administrator at webmaster@themobilesapp.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error. More information about this error
>   may be available in the server error log. Additionally, a 500 Internal
>   Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**htaccess file with all codes**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^themobilesapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.themobilesapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ specification.php?abc=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?abc=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^ampnews/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ ampnews.php?abc=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you solve my problem @abhishek-gurjar ?

Comment: I am looking at this and it is working https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification.php/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029

Comment: And you want to remove .php from ampspecification part, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah.. exactly.. you are right....

Comment: Working url is https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification.php?url=Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029 but I want to make it clean like https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029 . If you will click on above link then you will find a error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^ampspecification/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /ampspecification.php?abc=$1 [L]
```

This code line solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a specific rule for this condition please try with below and let me know the result.

```
RewriteRule ^ampspecification/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ampspecification.php/$1 [L]
```

I am assuming you want to rewrite page to ampspecification.php/test_url.

In above we are rewriting the url which has 'ampspecification' at starting.

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteRule ^ampspecification/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ specification.php?abc=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is you original url on which you want rewriting?

Comment: I also try this **RewriteRule ^ampspecification/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ ampspecification.php?url=$1 [L]** but this is not working...

Comment: This is original url https://www.themobilesapp.com/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029  and for this I use your recommended code **RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]**

Comment: No bro. It is not working. Btw, whole .htaccess code is running on my website with your help.

Comment: Bro. I'm not redirecting **specification.php* page on **ampspecification.php**  page. **ampspecification.php**  page is other page for Google AMP for better search result of mobile.  Normal page https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029 and this is **AMP** page https://www.themobilesapp.com/ampspecification/Nokia-Lumia-638-specifications-3029

Comment: Brother I am confused do you want it that way like ampspecification.php?abc=$1 same as specification.php, please clarify exact original on which you want to rewrite.I understand your problem but unable to replicate on my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165871/discussion-between-amarprem-cool-and-abhishek-gurjar).